# Click on imageView crashes if image not loaded from url

Tags: java, android, android-intent, imageview, picasso

I am using endless recycler view to show multiple posts. but if my internet speed is slow and image not loaded on time when I click on imageview it crashes the app. 
I am sending url from activity to another through intent.

Here is the code

RecyclerAdapter.java

```
 holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
  String icon = jsonData.get((position)).getImg();
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, Detail.class);
  intent.putExtra("app_icon", icon);
  }
  context.startActivity(intent);
```

Detail.java

```
     detail_icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detail_icon);
    String appicon = getIntent().getStringExtra("app_icon");
      try {
            detail_icon.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(appicon).getContent()));
    }catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Crashing on this line while image is not loaded and I click on imageview.

```
   detail_icon.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(appicon).getContent()));
```

Logcat

```
        Process: com.example.lenovo.connectiontest, PID: 26525
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lenovo.connectiontest/com.example.lenovo.connectiontest.Activity.Detail}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

   at com.example.lenovo.connectiontest.Activity.Detail.onCreate(Detail.java:233)
```

Comment: download that image on separate thread. Once the image is downloaded then set that to the image view

Comment: Use Glide or Picasso for image loading

Comment: Use **`glide`** or **`Picasso`** to load image from url

Comment: already using Picasso @Prem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its solved my problem

```
  Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    try  {
        //Your code goes here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
  });

  thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Glide?
Add this to your app level Gradle file:

```
// Glide image library

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

And then use it in any activity with the provided URL, the image is cached and doesn't need to be downloaded again (*in my case!*)
Then add this to your Activity:

```
Glide.with(this).load(urlProfileImg)

                .crossFade()

                .thumbnail(0.5f)

                .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))

                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)

                .into(imgProfile);
```

Or maybe try using Picasso - it has a superclass that you can override while the image is loading:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(target, new Callback(){ @Override public void onSuccess() { } @Override public void onError() { } });
```

*Sorry for the bad code formatting!*
I hope this helps!